# MongoDb(pymongo) фильтры

Tags: python, mongodb, база-данных

Ищу по коллекции все значения поля **title**, включающие слово "Tom":

> for item in
> db.order.find({'title':'Tom'}):
>
> ```
>      print item['title']
> ```

Если имеется в массиве поле title со значением **'Tom'**, то мы найдем это поле, но
если значение поля будет **'Hello Tom'**, то мы не получим ничего. Вопрос состоит в том, как сделать более 'легкий' фильтр, который найдет результат, если даже значение будет   sdfdsfdfsdfd**Tom**dfdsf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поискать по регекспе 'Tom':

```
for item in db.order.find({'title': { '$regex': 'Tom' }}):
     print item['title']
```

Comment: ага, ну вот типо того я написал в посте выше, только чтоб для всей записи или же для нескольких полей, не удалось реализовать

Comment: если у вас версия монги 2.6 и выше, то там есть text search, это то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

> for item in db.order.find({'descr':
> re.compile('Tom')}):